# New website on https, do I need to set up redirect?

Tags: redirect, https

We have an e-commerce website with in 4 languages running on ourbrand.com, ourbrand.de, ourbrand.fr etc. Currently 3 of those are running on http and the last one we are just ready to launch will be on https. I am trying to figure out if and how I need to set up htaccess redirect.

There is no history of running this new website on http (so no need to redirect existing http traffic), but I am sure that some people will type ourbrand.it or www.ourbrand.it directly to their browser's address bar. As far as I know, browser will default it to http://ourbrand.it right? So do I need to set up redirect to https? Which one? 301? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because as you said, if your visitors type ourbrand.it the browser will default to http://ourbrand.it

The best thing to do is a 301 (permamant) redirect.

If you want to improve security and avoid that first redirect, your should look into HSTS and HSTS preload.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I will definitely look into HSTS. We are also planning to move all ourbrand.xx websites to https in near future. Would HSTS be a solution for that without .htaccess 301 redirects? Will that be ok for google? There is some existing http traffic on those 3 domains I mentioned and also some SEO has been made (existing backlinks). Thank you!

Comment: HSTS is need a first visit and HSTS preloaded only apply to some browsers, and if updated, so a 301 redirect is always necessary.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly 301 redirects are necessary for all our domains (for compatibility reasons http://caniuse.com/#feat=stricttransportsecurity) and HSTS is a "benefit" for newer browsers. Right?